# gulp-rev not working with gulp-watch

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-rev, gulp-rename

Below is my code My main issue I have to watch changes of js and css and also based on that generate min file with proper version also my output directory is same that is also one case.

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
let cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var jsArr = [
    'search/media/src/js/*.js',
    //'common/media/js/*.js',
    '!search/media/src/js/*.testmin.js',
    '!search/media/src/js/*.min.js'
            // '!common/media/js/*.testmin.js',
];

var cssArr = [
    'search/media/css/*.css',
    '!search/media/css/*.testmin.css',
    '!search/media/css/*.min.css'
];


gulp.task('js', function () {
    //return gulp.src(jsArr, {base: './'})
    return gulp.src(jsArr)
            .pipe(watch(jsArr))
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(rename({suffix: '.testmin'}))
            .pipe(rev())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
                return file.base;
            }))
            .pipe(rev.manifest({
                merge: true
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('css', function () {
    //return gulp.src(cssArr, {base: './'})
    return gulp.src(cssArr)
            .pipe(watch(cssArr))
            .pipe(cleanCSS())
            .pipe(rename({suffix: '.testmin'}))
            .pipe(rev())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
                return file.base;
            }))
            .pipe(rev.manifest({
                merge: true
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['js', 'css'], function () {
});

var watcher = gulp.watch([jsArr, cssArr], ['default']);
watcher.on('change', function (event) {
    console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little testing and was able to get gulp-watch working by wrapping `watcher.on('change`)` within a gulp task. It would have to be within a gulp task in order to call it.

```
gulp.task( 'watch', function () {

    var watcher = gulp.watch( [jsArr, cssArr], ['default'] );

    watcher.on('change', function (event) {
        console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
    });

});
```

You could also set it up this way, if you'd like. This will watch the js and css tasks separate from one another.

```
gulp.task( 'watch', function () {
    gulp.watch( jsArr, ['js'] );
    gulp.watch( cssArr, ['css'] );
});
```

Also, you'll want to remove `pipe(watch(jsArr))` and `pipe(watch(cssArr))`. I'm not actually sure if gulp-watch can be used this way, as I have never used it this way, but when running `gulp watch` it would cause the task to hang and not complete.

To start gulp watch, run `gulp watch` in your terminal.